# Grammaire de l'adjectif « nombreux »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

> [titre d'un article](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/divertissement/actualite/vladimir-poutine-humili%C3%A9-apr%C3%A8s-avoir-appris-que-de-nombreux-de-ses-hommes-refusent-de-se-battre/ar-AA19p74E?ocid=msedgntp&cvid=6f65439125a246bedfd0c1143ea6efb3&ei=53)
>
> Vladimir Poutine humilié après avoir appris que de nombreux *de ses hommes* refusent de se battre

Est-ce que depuis un certain temps on pourrait écrire quelque chose comme « de nombreux de X » ?

« Nombreux » pourrait être traité comme un nom ? Est-ce maintenant un nom ?

Ce n'est qu'un adjectif d'après le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nombreux).

Comment: C'est la Saint-Jacques…

Comment: @jlliagre Je le lis, c'est formatif, et d'autres le lisent ; mais je pensais qu'il y avait tant à apprendre du  plus ignorant des locuteurs d'une localité des plus reculées de la francophonie, comme en Afrique par exemple, locuteur duquel selon vous j'aurais encore pu tirer une leçon… Pourquoi désespérer de trouver autant d'inspiration dans une  publication, qui si humble soit-elle, est en métropole même, lue par le grand public  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Après réflexion, la phrase est grammaticalement acceptable.

Si on part de la phrase :

> [...] après avoir appris que de nombreux ***hommes*** refusent de se battre.

mais qu'on souhaite préciser qu'il s'agit des siens :

> [...] après avoir appris que de nombreux ***de ses hommes*** refusent de se battre.

***Nombreux*** y reste un adjectif, si on remplace *de nombreux* par le moribond *maint*, les deux formes sont irréprochables :

> [...] après avoir appris que ***maint hommes*** refusent de se battre.

> [...] après avoir appris que ***maint de ses hommes*** refusent de se battre.

On retrouve cette équivalence avec l'anglais *many* : *many men refuse* / *many of his men refuse*.

La tournure aurait été plus élégante mais peut-être trop littéraire écrite comme ceci :

> [...] après avoir appris que ***nombre de ses hommes*** refusent de se battre.

Comment: Comme cela force la nature pronominale de « maint », on se trouve devant la nécessité de considérer « de nombreux » comme un pronom, et somme toute on retombe dans le passé, le vieux, le désuet en remplaçant « maint » par « de nombreux », et en compliquant les choses (pas « _of many_ » en anglais). On n'a rien inventé.